# Find the start and the end of Programming Code in a whole Text

Tags: python, html, regex, python-2.7, parsing

i have html with text and also programming code (Generic), without any distinction or mark. There is a way in order to puts a mark for the start and the end of the code, suitable for any programming code?

For example:

```
start message

Hello this is an example

int main(){ 
char word1[21],word2[21]; 
int first; 
printf("Type in the first word (maximum 20 characters):\n"); 
scanf("%20s",word1); 

other text

ends
```

I want to obtain:

```
Hello this is an example

'''

int main(){ 
char word1[21],word2[21];  
int first; 
printf("Type in the first word (maximum 20 characters):\n"); 
scanf("%20s",word1); 

'''

other text
```

Comment: @hjpotter92 this is my problem. If there is some Python lib for identification of programming code...

Comment: @hjpotter92: He did say __there's no distinction or mark__

Comment: Nothing that can identify generic languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try an answer:

This is not possible within the constraints you have given (none).

If you have no limitation about which programming languages to expect and which other non-programming text (language, scientifc, street language) to expect, and you also have absolutely no delimiters, there is no way to distinguish the two.

The problem is that there are programming languages out there which may look very much like ordinary text - especially if the sample size is small.

If you have a dozen lines of [Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm), or [Rebol](http://www.rebol.com/docs/reference.html) you could do a statistical analysis of e.g. punctuation and special characters versus expected (low) values for ordinary text. This is especially likely to work, if code is always separated from text by a new paragraph or at least newlines.

But even then this is really hard. A [REBOL example](http://www.rebol.com/docs/services/code/simple.html):

```
REBOL [
    Title: "REBOL/Services Simple Example"
    Author: "Carl Sassenrath"
    Version: 1.0.0
]
url: http://www.rebol.net/cgi-bin/services.r
print "Loading client..." ; Used until it is built-into REBOL
do http://www.rebol.net/rebservices/client.r
print "Sending command..."
result: do-service url [info]
print ["Result:" mold/only result]
ask "Done."
```

The above paragraph very much looks like scientific text with footnotes `[info]` and url references.

Maybe there's always a `<br>` or `<p>` before and after code in your html?

However for very short code snippets such an analysis is likely to fail. Your html could also contain text that is very close to programming languages. Compare mathematical equations or formula to something such as [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29#Examples) or [R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Vectors-and-assignment)

```
x <- c(10.4, 5.6, 3.1, 6.4, 21.7)
```

How is the above different from a thesis on a mathematical topic?

**So you must do a compromise.**

Some ways to proceed:

- Restrict the amount of programming languages detected (possibly "cryptic" ones that use lots of sepcial characters such as Perl, and C (braces), or Python (indentation and colons))
- Add markers to html or accept that `<br>`, or `<p>` or even just `\n` are valid delimiters. Surely the html contains `<verbatim>` or other tags to separate the code?

Then do some statistical analysis on

- Usage of special chars,
- Changing indentation levels,
- Variance of line length,
- Amount of unique words in use
- Repetition of words (command and variable names may be repeated more than ordinary words in text)
- Language markers ("the" is rare in code, but often used in language)